# Symfony2: The requested URL /app_dev.php/security/login_check was not found on this server

Tags: url, symfony, annotations, ubuntu-11.10

I'm having an issue whenever I try to log in, however this issue occurs only with the a Ubuntu Server where the site is uploaded and using wamp on windows works just fine.

I had no idea what's wrong with it. I don't see anything on the log file.

Here's the security.yml file:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Op\AppSecurityBundle\Entity\User: sha512
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

providers:
    default:
        entity: { class: AppSecurityBundle:User, property: email }

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_OPTIME_ADMIN:  ROLE_OPT_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:   [ROLE_OPT_USER, ROLE_OPT_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    prizes:
        pattern:    ^/admin|^/security|^/landing|^/reports|^/catalog
        form_login:
            check_path: /security/login_check
            login_path: /
            provider: default
            success_handler: whos_online
            failure_handler: whos_online
        logout:
            path:   /security/logout
            target: /
            success_handler: whos_online

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_OPT_ADMIN] }
    - { path: ^/security, roles: [ROLE_OPT_ADMIN, ROLE_OPT_USER] }
    - { path: ^/landing, roles: [ROLE_OPT_ADMIN, ROLE_OPT_USER] }
    - { path: ^/reports, roles: [ROLE_OPT_ADMIN, ROLE_OPT_USER] }
    - { path: ^/catalog, roles: [ROLE_OPT_ADMIN] }
```

routing_dev.yml

```
_assetic:
    resource: .
    type:     assetic

_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

routing.yml

```
ws:
    resource: "@BeSimpleSoapBundle/Resources/config/routing/webservicecontroller.xml"
    prefix:   /ws

security:
    resource: @AppSecurityBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

parameter:
    resource: @ParameterBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

status:
    resource: @AppStatusBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

csc:
    resource: @CSCBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

catalog:
    resource: @CatalogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

prizes:
    resource: @PrizesBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

reports:
    resource: @ReportsBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
```

AppSecurityBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
_security:
    resource: "@AppSecurityBundle/Controller/AppSecurityController.php"
    type:     annotation
```

Annotations in AppSecurityController.php

```
            /**
     * @Route("/", name="_login")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function loginAction( )
    {
         //hidden
        }

/**
     * @Route("/security/login_check", name="_security_check")
     */
    public function securityCheckAction( )
    {
        // The security layer will intercept this request
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/security/logout", name="_logout")
     */
    public function logoutAction( )
    {
        // The security layer will intercept this request
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/landing", name="_landing")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function landingAction( )
    {
        return array ( );
    }
```

I apologize if this is a stupid question. I have no idea why it works locally but not on the server.

I'm using Symfony 2.0.12, and Ubuntu Server 11.10

Added:
When I run php app/console router:debug I get

```
[router] Current routes
Name                     Method Pattern
_wdt                     ANY    /_wdt/{token}
_profiler_search         ANY    /_profiler/search
_profiler_purge          ANY    /_profiler/purge
_profiler_import         ANY    /_profiler/import
_profiler_export         ANY    /_profiler/export/{token}.txt
_profiler_search_results ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results
_profiler                ANY    /_profiler/{token}
_webservice_call         POST   /ws/{webservice}
_webservice_definition   GET    /ws/{webservice}
_login                   ANY    /
_security_check          ANY    /security/login_check
_logout                  ANY    /security/logout
_landing                 ANY    /landing
_concurrency             ANY    /security/concurrency
_overwriteConcurrency    ANY    /security/overwriteConcurrency
_loading                 ANY    /security/loading
_changeLanguage          ANY    /changeLanguage
_security                ANY    /security/{strategy}/{globalStrategy}
_parameter               ANY    /admin/{strategy}/{globalStrategy}
_status                  ANY    /admin/{strategy}/{globalStrategy}
_csc                     ANY    /admin/{strategy}/{globalStrategy}
_catalogs                ANY    /catalog/{strategy}/{globalStrategy}
_prizes                  ANY    /admin/{strategy}/{globalStrategy}
_reports                 ANY    /{globalStrategy}/{strategy}
```

Comment: You made sure your server is compliant with Symfony2 requirements? In your YML file, try to use route names instead of path (not if it works with Symfony2.0). When you run `php app/console router:debug` on your server, can you find the route in the list? All the other URL work on your server?

Comment: Edited post with result of php app/console router:debug

Comment: What do you mean by route names instead of path?

Comment: try `^/(admin|security|landing|reports|catalog)` as pattern

Comment: Hi Pazi, it didn't work :(

Comment: Does your server meet all requirements (i.e. run `php app/check.php`)? In your `security.yml` file, instead of using `/security/login_check` try using the route name `_security_check`.. I'd read the doc again to see if there are any warning messages about this issue.

Comment: Everything says OK, except "short_open_tag" but I already changed it in the right PHP.ini and still says that. I changed what you said, It throws ->> InvalidConfigurationException: Invalid configuration for path "security.firewalls.prizes": The check_path "_security_check" for login method "form_login" is not matched by the firewall pattern "^/admin|^/security|^/landing|^/reports|^/catalog".

Comment: The short_open_tag says 
[[WARNING]] Checking that php.ini has short_open_tag set to off: FAILED
*** Set short_open_tag to off in php.ini ***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

had the same issue once, in my case i didnt have my server well configured, i fix it by configuring apache2 with the rewrite module, in linux it should by sometinhg like this sudo a2enmod rewrite, pluss in your site configuration site in etc/apache/sites-available/example.dev you should have something like this

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
  ServerName example.dev
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/intranetcms/web"
  DirectoryIndex app.php
  <Directory "/var/www/intranetcms/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

if you dont know how to configure a local domain here is an example http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/configuration-and-templating.html 
but if you dont feel like configuring a local domain you can check the default site configuration file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default and change AllowOverride None for AllowOverride All